# Using htaccess to serve file from a remote server

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, mod-proxy

Is it possible to do this using htaccess?

User access -> http:// mydomaina.com/dir/filename

and it will display the content from -> http:// mymainsite.com/anydir/mydomaina-filename

i did have a htaccess code but its not working maybe theres something missing

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteRule ^dir/(.*)\.xml$ http://mymainsite.com/dir/%{HTTP_HOST}-$1.xml [P] 
 </IfModule>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are there any errors in the Apache error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [RTFM](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)ed. It said:

```
^/somepath(.*) /otherpath$1 [P]                 doesn't make sense, not supported
...
^/somepath(.*) http://otherhost/otherpath$1 [P] http://otherhost/otherpath/pathinfo
                                            via internal proxy
```

So it looks like it should work. But..

```
Note: mod_proxy must be enabled in order to use this flag.
```

> its not working

This is not a meaningful error message. What do your log files show? What happens if you try sending a redirect instead of proxying?

C.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is that mod_rewrite isn't on.  Just loading the module isn't enough.  Somewhere in your config you also need `RewriteEngine On` to enable it.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine